# Closing a toast message in lightning

Tags: lightning

I am displaying a toast message showing errors when the user submits the form. The errors are displayed with a x to close the panel. However, the x isn't closing it, and I would like to close the toast message automatically when the user fixes the errors and submits the form again.

Answer (score 5):

There is no API for closing a toast. However, you can specify a duration for the toast:

```
var toast = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
toast.setParams({ message: someMessage, duration: 5000 });
toast.fire();
```

Comment: Thanks sfdcfox, the requirement is to leave the box until the user has read it all and fixed the errors and resubmit. if I launch another toast message for a quick millisecond, would the first one go away? i assume you can have one toast msg at a time?

Comment: @Sheida Toasts are not meant to do that, and are not designed to support that. You'll have to create a component and show it using CSS. Toasts cannot be displayed for fewer than 5000 ms (it'll be bumped up to 5000 if you try). Also, toasts are placed in a queue, so the second wouldn't overwrite the first anyways.